# Android: Navigation Drawer Layout Dynamically change icon

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view, navigation-drawer

[image]

Is there way to dynamically change the image of the hamburger menu icon for navigation drawers?My use case is that per fragment in my nav menu I color the action bar based on what is being viewed, so sometimes I need white icons or black icons.

It doesn't seem like there is a way is there? Is there possibly a work around I can use such as constantly reloading the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` I use to toggle the navigation drawer etc?

I guess I could possible try to use reflection and change the drawable on the fly, but I'd need to dig through the navigation source to make sure what I am changing doesn't break anything.

Comment: menu icon means 3 vertical lines?

then my answer works, i tried it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reload it again by setting the listener:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                newDrawable, R.string.app_name,
                newDrawable) {

    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    };

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    };

};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Will try it in a moment

Comment: Hey, did it work for you perfectly? I guess it worked since you accept this answer. I need some help on this similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic padding to indent the hamburger menu icon.

1. Set `DrawerListener`

   ```
   density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
   maxIconIndent = (int) (density * 8.0f);

   mDrawerIcon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ic_drawer);
   drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
   drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);
   ```
2. override onDrawerSlide method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float v) {
       int indent = (int) (v * maxIconIndent);
       mDrawerIcon.setPadding(-indent, 0, (int) (density * 8.0f), 0);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {
   }
   ```

`mDrawerIcon` is your hamburger menu view.